# identify an executable compiler and decompile it ..?

Tags: compilation

I want to identify an executable compiler and decompile it. It's itools (for iphone). It comes in Chinese only. So, I want to translate or add English to the tool. But i don't know what language tool written by and what compiler tool compiled with. So, I need your help.

Comment: It is too broad, and it might be illegal to help you in some countries. BTW, "identify an executable compiler" is ambiguous. Do you want to guess the compiler used to produce that executable (sometimes the Linux `string` utility might help, since it gives all the putative strings inside the binary, and some string might be characteristic of the compiler)

Comment: as i said, i only want to translate the tool .. nothing else .. but thx anyway.

Comment: That's not how this works. Compilation, especially with optimizations is not a 1-to-1 reversible operation.

Comment: And what you want is probably technically impossible, or more difficult than rewriting the software from scatch.

Comment: i got it, forget about decompile the program .. now i need any tool can edit the program resources such as (Text, Buttons and Icons) .. is there any ?.